# ClosedXML enable Autofilter in protected sheet

Tags: c#, closedxml

I am adding an Autofilter to my worksheets and protect my worksheet:

```
oSheet.Range(StartRange, EndRange).SetAutoFilter();
oSheet.Protect("xxxx");
```

Obviously this has the effect of disabling the Autofilter, which i need enabled. I have tired to add:

```
oSheet.AutoFilter.Enabled =true;
```

Both before and after the protect statement to no effect. I have also tried to add the filter after the sheet protection. Also no effect. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
oSheet.Protect("xxxx").SetAutoFilter();
```

More protection options at https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Sheet-Protection

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a go

Comment: Can't find this extension method in 0.95.4. Do you need to install some additional package?